# how can convert json object to array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this JSON

```
[size: null, color: "white"]
```

Which send to the server via post method.

I try

```
$your_json_string = json_decode($your_json_string, TRUE)
```

and

```
$your_json_string = html_entity_decode($your_json_string);
$your_json_string = json_decode($your_json_string, true);
```

- With `print_r($your_json_string);` I get: *null*.
- With `echo json_last_error();` I get: *4*.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: The json string is invalid. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: A JSON object should look like `{"size": null, "color": "white"}`. Objects are surrounded with `{}`, not `[]`. Keys have to be quoted.

Comment: You shouldn't try to construct JSON by hand. Use `json_encode()` to create it, and it will be formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

1) that is a json array [] not an object {}.
2) it will want property names quoted.

```
$String = <<< LOL
{"size": null, "color": "white"}
LOL;

print_r(json_decode($String,TRUE));
```

then you get

```
Array
(
    [size] =>
    [color] => white
)
```

Comment: Use `var_dump` rather than `print_r`, you get a more detailed result.

Comment: This is technically incorrect; it is not valid JSON at all.

Comment: @EdCottrell i literally copy and pasted it from my working test.php on my desktop it is correct.

Comment: I didn’t say your code was wrong. I said that the “JSON” in question is not JSON. Your first statement is incorrect. It’s not an array and it doesn’t “want property names quoted.” The problem is that the “JSON” in the question is not, in fact, JSON, but your answer incorrectly states that it is.

Comment: it will 3000 want the property names quoted. php json_decode will bomb otherwise.

Comment: I’m afraid you’re missing the point. Yes, JSON *requires* (not “wants”) quotation marks there. But the thing in question is not JSON, much less “a json [sic] array.” Your answer states, incorrectly, that it is. I will be happy to remove the downvote if you make that correction, but as it is, your answer is still, objectively wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have a wrong json string** and you don't know how it will convert json to array in php. Example Below:

```
$string = '{test ing,test ingredients,test ingredients3,test ingredients4,test ingredients5}';
```

Trim your json string and remove non required data.

```
    $string = ltrim($string, '{');
    $string = rtrim($string, '}');
```

Remove comma from string and get normal php array

```
    $newSting = explode(',', $string);
```

Now you can loop through your data

```
foreach ($newSting as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
```